# Classic book about a rich, spoiled teenager who accidentally finds himself on a working fishing boat for a season

Tags: identification-request

I read this book in the 1960
-1970 time period, but the story would have taken place in the 1930s or 1940s.  I remember that the rich, spoiled teenager was drinking in a lounge aboard an ocean liner.  A storm blew up, and he was rescued by the crew of a fishing vessel.  He demanded that the crew return him to his rich father, but their captain informed him that they were out for the season and if he wanted to eat, he’d have to work.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Captains Courageous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captains_Courageous)*, by Rudyard Kipling, 1897.

> Protagonist Harvey Cheyne Jr., is the spoiled son of a wealthy California railroad magnate. Washed overboard from a transatlantic steamship and rescued by the crew of the fishing schooner We're Here off the Grand Banks of Newfoundland, Harvey can neither persuade them to take him quickly to port, nor convince them of his wealth. Harvey accuses the captain, Disko Troop, of taking his money (which is later revealed to be on the deck from which Harvey fell). Troop bloodies his nose but takes him in as a boy on the crew until they return to port. Harvey comes to accept his situation.
>
> Through a series of trials and adventures, Harvey, with the help of the captain's son Dan Troop, becomes acclimated to the fishing lifestyle, and even skillful, such as becoming responsible for the ship's accounts of its catch. Great stories of the cod fishery with references to New England whaling and 19th-century steam and sailing are intertwined with the We're Here's adventures during a season at sea. Eventually, the We're Here returns to port and Harvey wires his parents, who immediately hasten to Boston, Massachusetts, and thence to the fishing town of Gloucester to recover him. The Cheynes are amazed by their son's newfound maturity, and reward the seaman Manuel, who initially rescued Harvey. Harvey's father hires Dan to work on his prestigious tea clipper fleet, and Harvey goes to Stanford to prepare for taking over his father's shipping lines.

Comment: Please expand your answer with details explaining how it matches the question. See [Guidelines for good story-ID answers?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/840/11259)

Comment: I've made a quick edit to add a Wikipedia link and summary. FWIW, that's usually the minimum we demand of identification answers. Ideally, quotations, whether from the work or the review, are added to further prove a match.